# Toolbar is clipped underneath the system bar

Tags: android, themes, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, coordinator-layout

As found on the internet I use a translucent system bar, a CoordinatorLayoutwith an AppBarLayoutand a Toolbar. Scrolling with the NestedScrollViewmoves the toolbar to the top, underneath the systembar, but some pixels are left behind. This looks quite ugly:

[image: scrolled with some left over pixels]

So here comes some details:

- compileSdkVersion 23
- buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
- minSdkVersion 21
- targetSdkVersion 23
- 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
- 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'

styles:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#22DDAA</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#ffffff</item>

        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>

        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <!--<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>-->
        <!--<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">false</item>-->
    </style>
```

layout:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/gradient"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_password_forgot_coordinator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
                app:elevation="0dp">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/actionbar_title"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/text_white_strong"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor..."/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

By the way: I need to use this RelativeLayout / ImageView combination for a large image in the background which should also be visible under the system bar. For this question only I am using the gradient...

---

OK, I patched my layout to this:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <RelativeLayout>
            <ImageView/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar/>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
            <LinearLayout>
                <TextView/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now it looks like this:

[image: toolbar too high]

Then I tried android:fitsSystemWindows="true" in lots of variations, but I cannot get that Toolbar below that systembar (without the systembar getting grey...)

Comment: The CoordinatorLayout should be the parent view. You can get the same result with your RelativeLayout/ImageView when having them as children of CL.

Comment: android:fitsSystemWindows="true" on the Toolbar and AppBarLayout. And yes, remove the RelativeLayout, please

Answer (score 0):

CoordinatorLayout is supposed to be the root layout. Like @алекскей said you don't need RelativeLayout at all. You won't even need fitSystemWindows as well.